# How to set condtion in shopping cart to apply discount only for product between two price ranges

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, rules

I need a condition in magento shopping cart price rules where we can set discount for products  between two price ranges . For example: I need to apply discount for product that are in between $100 and $200
[image: Condition Applied]

[image: action]

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: `If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    If total quantity  equals or greater than  1  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
        Price in cart  equals or greater than  170 
        Price in cart  equals or less than  600'

Comment: This is what I have set so far. Only issue it doesn't make sense when I apply for Price in cart equals or less than 600' because it will set discount for products below 170 too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do like so?:
[image: Shopping cart price rule]

I tested it, seems to work on my system..

This one only applies discount on items in the specified range:

[image: Price rule 2]

Comment: Yes I have tried that . this method will affect the subtotal. But not the products in the cart. What I need is coupon should be validated only for products that are in the specified prize range.

Comment: I updated my answer, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi @anja I updated My question. check now. I have follwed your method, But still it is taking products that are lower than 200

Comment: What if you remove all the stuff in the Conditions?

Comment: If I remove the less than or equal to , it will only take only take products greater than 200

Comment: Did you press the red x on those 3 lines in the Conditions tab? so it should only take the rule from Actions

Comment: Great! :) glad I could help